# How to JOIN two rows into one row SQL

Tags: sql

Table 1:

| ID | Name | Class | Date | Intime | Outtime | INAM | OUTPM |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | Smith | 1st | 07-12-2022 | 8:30 AM | Null | P | Null |
| 1 | Smith | 1st | 07-12-2022 | Null | 4:30 PM | Null | P |

How to join these two rows into a single row?

Required output:

| ID | Name | Class | Date | Intime | Outtime | INAM | OUTPM |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | Smith | 1st | 07-12-2022 | 8:30 AM | 4:30 PM | P | P |

Can someone please help me to join into a single row? Thank you...

Comment: You need no provide further sample data, please. For these two rows, you could just select the maximum of each column. It's unclear if this will be sufficient for the whole table.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You may aggregate by the first 4 columns and take the max of the final 4 columns:

```sql
SELECT ID, Name, Class, Date,
       MAX(Intime) AS Intime, MAX(Outtime) AS Outtime, MAX(INAM) AS INAM,
       MAX(OUTPM) AS OUTPM
FROM yourTable
GROUP BY ID, Name, Class, Date;
```

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT
    FK,
    MAX(Field1) AS Field1,
    MAX(Field2) AS Field2
FROM
    table1
GROUP BY
    FK;
```

I used MAX, but any aggregate which picks one value from among the GROUP BY rows should work.

Test data:

```
CREATE TABLE table1 (FK int, Field1 varchar(10), Field2 varchar(10));

INSERT INTO table1 VALUES (3, 'ABC', NULL);
INSERT INTO table1 VALUES (3, NULL, 'DEF');
INSERT INTO table1 VALUES (4, 'GHI', NULL);
INSERT INTO table1 VALUES (4, 'JKL', 'MNO');
INSERT INTO table1 VALUES (4, NULL, 'PQR');
```

Results:

```
FK  Field1  Field2
--  ------  ------
3   ABC     DEF
4   JKL     PQR
```

Comment: There are no fields in a DB.